# Mask when condition is met as well as all subequent values on row (without using a loop)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mask

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30, 11, 9], [13, 16, 21, 10, 9], [11, 5, 23, 50, 0]])
```

I would like a mask that shows if any row has a value > 20.  If a True, then all subsequent values on that row should also be True.

e.g first row should read as:

```
False, False, True, True, True
```

I don't know how to do it without using a loop.

Comment: [`x.gt(20).cummax(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)?